# Use a UIViewController's Subclass property as IBOutlet in another Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have a UIViewController's subclass, we call it **MySuperClass** , this subclass has a **UITableView** property which is than initalized programmatically.
Now I want to subclass **MySuperClass** to **MySubclass** but this time I'd like to design the tableview via Interface Builder rather than programmatically.
What I want is something similar to how **UIViewController** works, if you subclass UIViewController it has its view property already initalized, but when you bring it into IB you can link it to an Interface Builder's UIView item, how do I do this?

the source code of my superclass is something similar to this one:

```
//interface

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MySuperClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;


//implementation


#import "MySuperClass.h"


@implementation MySuperClass

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        [self initializeProperties];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib{

    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self initializeProperties];

}

- (void) initializeProperties{

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame style: UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    UIView *tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.bannerView.frame.size.height+kBannerDistance)];

    tableHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just "redeclare" the `@property` in your subclass.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MySuperClass.h"

@interface MySubClass : MySuperClass

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

The compiler will be clever enough to understand your are referencing the super class property, and IB will have no problem linking to the subclass's one.

Comment: isn't it reinitalized by awakeFromNib than?

Comment: The `tableView` set from the IB will be replaced by the `tableView` initialized in `initializeProperties`. So basically this solution will make the subclass useless.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not be the best solution, but it should get it done.

Define `- initFromSubClassWithNibName: bundle:;` in `MySuperClass.h` and implement it like this:

```
- (id) initFromSubClassWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    return [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
}
```

and in `MySubClass`

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    return [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]; 
}
```

This way you can escape `MySuperView`'s implementation of the `init` method and use `UIViewController's implementation. You can take the same approach with`awakeFromNib`. This will avoid creating a table view programmatically.

Then you can take GuillaumeA's answer to initialize `tableView` from the IB.